# Whole Colors change when I change Colors in my Java Paint Program

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I created a program in Java using JPanel and Graphics. This is simple Paint Panel program in which things draw when we drag mouse and when we want to make line with different color simply just press the button in a panel but the problem  is that when I press a button in panel and drag the mouse whole components present in a panel turns into that color (Button' Color).

Code:

```
public class PaintAssign extends JPanel {
    private ArrayList<Point> points= new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Point> points2= new ArrayList<>();
    public final JButton[] panelButton=new JButton[5];
    public String[] colors={"RED","BLUE","GREEN","YELLOW","CYAN"};
    int x=0;

    public PaintAssign()
    {  addMouseMotionListener(
        new MouseMotionAdapter(){
           @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
            {

                points.add(e.getPoint());

                repaint();
            }
        });

        addMouseListener(
        new MouseAdapter(){

       });

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle(22, 22);                
            panelButton[i] = new JButton();
            panelButton[i].setText(colors[i]);
            panelButton[i].setOpaque(true);
            panelButton[i].setBounds(r);
            this.add(panelButton[i]);
            this.setVisible(true);
        }

        mouseAction handle=new mouseAction();
        panelButton[0].addActionListener(handle);
        panelButton[1].addActionListener(handle);
        panelButton[2].addActionListener(handle);
        panelButton[3].addActionListener(handle);
        panelButton[4].addActionListener(handle);

   }

   private class mouseAction implements ActionListener
    {
       @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if(e.getSource()==panelButton[0])
            {
                x=1;
            }
            else if(e.getSource()==panelButton[1])
            {
                x=2;
            }
            else if(e.getSource()==panelButton[2])
            {

                x=3;
            }

            else if(e.getSource()==panelButton[3])
            {
                x=4;
            }
            else if(e.getSource()==panelButton[4])
            {

                x=5;
             }
        }

    }

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(x==0)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
        else if(x==1)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
        }

        else if(x==2)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
        else if(x==3)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
        else if(x==4)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        }else if(x==5)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        }



        for(Point i:points)
        {
            g.fillOval(i.x,i.y,15,15);
        }


    }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

The paintComponent method is called everytime the panel redraw itself and that happens quite often. Then when you set the color, all the points will be redrawn with the new color.

To avoid this behavior you must save not only the coordinates of your points but also their color.

```
public class PaintAssign extends JPanel {
    private ArrayList<Point> points= new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Color> colors = new ArrayList<>();

   //....

  public PaintAssign(){  
      addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter(){
          @Override
          public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            points.add(e.getPoint());
            if(x==0) {
                 colors.add(Color.BLACK);
            } else if(x==1) {
                 colors.add(Color.RED);
            } else if(x==2) {
                 colors.add(Color.BLUE);
            } else if(x==3) {
                 colors.add(Color.GREEN);
            } else if(x==4) {
                 colors.add(Color.YELLOW);
            }else if(x==5) {
                 colors.add(Color.CYAN);
            }

            repaint();
        }
    });

    // ...

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       super.paintComponent(g);

       for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
           g.setColor(colors.get(i));
           g.fillOval(points.get(i).x, points.get(i).y, 15, 15);
       }
    }
}
```

Consider creating a new class Point containing the coordinates and the color of the point.

Comment: @AndrewThompson you're right, creating a class encapsulating the two properties is better. I just pointed that in the end of my answer but didn't give a code. I'll update my answer or feel free to update it.

Answer (score 0):

You didn' provide the repaint() method, but my guess is, since you record all your points to the same list, all points are redrawn in the same color. What you need are separate lists for every component you draw, managed in a way that you can access that list when the component is selected.

I'm not sure if I understood your problem correctly though, maybe you could provide more details.